# How can I stretch images while preserving corners using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, node-imagemagick

I want to stretch images, while preserving 4 corners intact. Similar stuff in iOS is setting [capInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/capInsets), for UIImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a hash symbol (tic-tac-toe grid) on your image, with the
corner squares being the part you don't want to distort.

1. Divide your image into 3 subimages at the vertical lines with the
   -crop option.
2. Stretch (or compress) the middle image horizontally.
3. Reassemble the 3 parts into one image (+append)
4. Divide the image into 3 subimages at the horizontal lines with
   -crop.
5. Stretch the middle piece vertically.
6. Reassemble (-append).

Comment: you are right. I just wondered if there's more neat way to do it.

Comment: I tried a couple of things like the new "-distort shepard" feature but did not get the result I expected.  I'm sure my 6-step procedure could be reduced to one ImageMagick commandline.